# Phalcon Session Array (Shopping Cart)

Tags: arrays, session, cart, phalcon

I'm having a hard time getting information in regards to phalcon sessions / shopping cart.

I want to save session variables in an array and then echo it out on my view.phtml and then save it within my database when they "checkout". 
I've tried this code below to store it as an array when addtoCartAction is called:

```
 $this->session->set('item',['Description' => $menu_item->getDescription(), 'Price' => $menu_item->getPrice()]);
```

and then echo with :

```
 $thisItem = $this->session->get("item");
 echo $thisItem;
```

But nothing seems to be stored in the array when the view renders.
Any tips would be awesome thanks

Comment: `echo $thisItem['Description'];` ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it's still echoing an empty array . . .

Answer (score 1):

```
 $this->session->set('item',[
     'Description' => $menu_item->getDescription(),
     'Price' => $menu_item->getPrice()
 ]);

// try to check the session 
var_dump( $this->session->has('item'));
var_dump( $this->session->status());

// and echo it 
   echo $this->session->get('item')['Description'];
   echo $this->session->get('item')['Price'];
```